# How do you cope with emacs halting on receiving big input?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am developing project in clojure using emacs cider under windows. And sometimes I have a problem that after accidently forgotten println function or on printing contents of big file Emacs stops responding (cursor and all key combinations doesn't work) and retire into oneself for processing that information to show it in repl. The only way to continue I know is to close program and open project files from scratch. And it is so simple to get in this trap.

Are there any other better solutions or configuration restrictions?

Comment: Keep hitting `C-c C-c` (interrupt) and / or `C-g`. You need to do this often enough that you have a chance of interrupting the connection.

Comment: Good advice. It brings hope of reviving work layout. I will try this more persistently the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though this suggestion will not solve your problem completely, it can help you a little.

First, set `*print-length*` to some value to limit the number of items of each collection to be printed.

```
(set! *print-length* 10)
```

And use `cider-connect` instead of `cider-jack-in`. You should run `lein repl` in a separate console window, then run `cider-connect` to connect to the repl. Then you can evaluate some expressions in the console window.

It would be good if there's an option to limit the contents to be printed by number of characters, however, I couldn't find it.